# How change return render direction in Symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I Have a problem rendering a form in symfony.

I use a comercial template (SmartAdmin) and this template use AJAX to capture all the urls loaded, keep the menus and configuration when the url provide '#'

Normally i can work ok, but in this controller i have a problem when the validation fails

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Clientes();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $url=$this->generateUrl('ec_main_cliente', array('idcliente' => $entity->getId()));
            $url = str_replace('cliente', '#cliente', $url);

            return $this->redirect($url);
        }



        return $this->render('ECMainBundle:Clientes:nuevo_cliente.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
```

When Form is Invalid , load "ECMainBundle:Clientes:nuevo_cliente.html.twig" without the "#" and lost all the menus and configurations.

Any suggestion please?

Thanks in Advance and sorry for my english

Image work Ok:
[image]

Image of the problem:
[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Could you please clarify what the problem is? I think it's in the paragraph below the code block … but I find hard to understand what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: hi, the problem is: the first time the form is show, work correct ( the menus and configuration of the theme work ok ). If the Form is Valid, in the redirect i can remplace cliente, for #cliente, and work ok ( the theme work correct thanks the '#' ) but, when is invalid, i lost all... i can`t see the menu and configuration, i dont have any idea to add the '#' in render. (thanks for reply)

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser or the log file?

Comment: No, any error, work ok ( the form work ok, if is invalid say the problem , for example, if i not put the Cliente, say, please insert the name Client, but in this momment i lost the theme because i cant add the '#' to the URL , i need insert the '#' in the url of the render the Twig template. (sorry for the bad explanaition )

Comment: add images to the first question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have the feeling to fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but I think that you want the redirect always take place. In this case you should restructure your code a bit:

```
$id = 0;

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    $id = $entity->getId();
}

$url = $this->generateUrl('ec_main_cliente', array('idcliente' => $id));
$url = str_replace('cliente', '#cliente', $url);

return $this->redirect($url);
```

Then, of course, the last part with the template rendering would be never exectuted.

Comment: in this case, if the form is invalid, not show the form and the errors